# Resume header - format the line in the header

Tags: formatting, header-footer, rules, cv, resume

In resume class, when the file is created in the header is a long horizontal line.
And this line appears on every page. How can I format the header to have the line only on the first page, but not on the next?
Here is an example: [image]

And the code for this example:

```
\documentclass[margin,line,a4paper]{resume}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, a4paper=true, pdfstartview=FitV,
linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
  I want this upper line
  \section{\mysidestyle Section}\vspace{1mm}
    \begin{description}
    \item This is the first page. And the above line is ok.
    \end{description}
  \newpage
  This is the next page. I don't want this line.


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\pagestyle{plain}% Set default page style
\thispagestyle{fancy}% Set page style of first page
```

in your preamble. The `plain` style is set as the default page style, while `\thispagestyle{fancy}` (which includes the header) is set only for the first page.

In the example, `fancy` and `plain` are very similar. If they are not and you *only* want to remove the header rule, then you can add the following as part of your document starting on page two:

```
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove current/subsequent page style header rule
```